# Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10011]: Invalid function from_timestamp

Tags: hive, impala

need helps here.

`select   from_timestamp(cast(mytime as timestamp) - interval 1 days, 'yyyy-MM-dd') from table`

I' using HIVE script and it returned with error message as below.

'Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10011]: Invalid function from_timestamp'

mytime field is a date + time format like 2022-10-05 00:00:00.

Seeking your help.

I have tried multiple ways but still unable to get through.

Answer (score 0):

if `mytime` is already timestamp column, you shouldnt try to convert to a timestamp.
Please use below

```
select date_format((mytime  - interval '1' day),'yyyy-MM-dd') mytime_yyyymmdd_string
```

Output will be a string in yyyy-MM-dd format.

`date_format` - This is a better function where you can use various java compatible format.